# Map a remote Cygwin path to a Windows drive

Tags: linux, cygwin

I use cygwin to log into remote Linux servers. I'm not very good with the Linux command-line, especially for editing files using tools like vi. So I wondered if it's possible to view a remote Linux path through Windows Explorer, letting me edit files with my familiar local tools like NotePad++, etc.

Not sure if cygwin is needed for this, or if some tool can do it directly... both are of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at WinSCP. Although it is a programm for file transfer, it offers you scripting and basic file manager functionality. The build in editor is kept pretty simple but your are able to use an external editor as well.

http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_editor#preference

Answer (score 2):

Never used it myself but take a look at Swish http://www.swish-sftp.org/

Looks like it offers exactly what you need sftp access from windows explorer.

I have always used filezilla on windows to browse sftp but it doesn't as far as I can tell intergrate with windows explorer.

Just noticed that Swish is an Alpha so be careful as it may be incomplete.